# Loading Assemblies with referenced dll's

Tags: c#, assemblies

I am trying to load assemblies into a new domain,
However I Keep getting an error that the file specified cannot be found,

Note that I have a Directory Called 'Extensions' that contains a Folder 'Inspect' which contains a number of dll's

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'InspectBLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'"
I am currently doing the following

```
    public AppDomain GetAppDomain(DirectoryInfo dir, string domainName)
    {
        var assemblydll = dir.GetFiles().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("ServerDLL"));
        AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
        domaininfo.ApplicationBase = dir.FullName;
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName, null, domaininfo);
        foreach (var item in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(item.FullName);
            domain.Load(bytes);
        }
        return domain;
    }
```

New Information that I Discovered, it seems that it is looking for the dll where the .exe is, which is bad. (I coppied the dlls to the exe all worked, however I need it to be in the Folder Extension\Inspect)

Comment: So what file is it trying to load? Have you tried searching the error online? Can you echo item.fullname And  check it exists?

Comment: it does exist, since I am using DirectoryInfo, I did check what file, and the file did exist in the folder, Im editing post for more info

Comment: Using Assembly.Load(byte[]) is in general a really bad idea, the assembly gets loaded without a loading context.  So the CLR will have a great deal of trouble finding dependent assemblies.  It certainly will have no clue that such an assembly is present in *dir* as well.  Other than *not* doing this, use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems, AppDomain.AssemblyResolve to assist the CLR in finding them.

Comment: I tried it with this aswell
                    var assName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(item.FullName);
                    domain.Load(assName);
Same Exception

Comment: I can't figure out why it won't load a dll unless the dll is in the same folder as the exe

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this with

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve
```